# Nested Angular Form Groups - Form must reflect HTML structure

Tags: forms, angular, typescript

Say I have the following formGroup structure:

```
userGroup = {
   name,
   surname,
   address: {
      firstLine,
      secondLine
   }
}
```

This forces me to write HTML similar to the following:

```
<form [formGroup]="userGroup">
   <input formControlName="name">
   <input formControlName="surname">

   <div formGroupName="address">
      <input formControlName="firstLine">
      <input formControlName="secondLine">
   </div>
</form>
```

Let's say, **just for the sake of the example**, that you are constrained to write HTML that looks like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="userGroup">
   <input formControlName="name">
   <input formControlName="surname">

   <div formGroupName="address">
      <input formControlName="firstLine">
   </div>

   <hr>
   <div formGroupName="someOtherGroup">
       <input id="problemSecondLine" formControlName="???.secondLine">
  </div>
</form>
```

Is there a way, to force the field with `id=problemSecondLine` to be under `userGroup -> address -> secondLine`, even though, visually, I have no option but to place it under this particular DIV?

I guess I can manually update via ngModel - but I'm trying to find the cleanest way possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `formControl` directive instead of `formControlName`

```
<input id="problemSecondLine" [formControl]="userGroup.get('address.secondLine')">
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/FjLUWDxEnTePO4a1UeAM?p=preview)**